# After upgrading from free Heroku Redis plan to the first paid tier, our app has crashed and won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, actioncable

We are a not for profit social media community. We upgraded from the free Heroku Redis plan to the lowest tier paid Heroku Redis plan.  Instead of improving performance, the site crashed.  And it's still down.

We got some help with the SSL issue, and updated sidekiq.rb and actioncable.yml (see below) but now redis can't connect to actioncable, and we're getting a slew of errors about not being able to connect.

Here is our sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.default_worker_options = {
  backtrace: true,
  retry: true
}

sidekiq_redis = lambda do
  Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 2, &sidekiq_redis)
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 17, &sidekiq_redis)
end

Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay!
```

Our cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV['REDIS_URL'] %>
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>
```

We are using the Heroku Redis $15/month plan now.  As soon as we upgraded, the site crashed.  Someone helped us update the sidekiq.rb and actioncable.yml, but the site still doesn't work.

Among other errors:

1. Redis::ConnectionError Sidekiq New Issue  Connection lost (ECONNRESET)
2. heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"
3. heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cable"
4. ECONNREFUSED

Comment: A protip is to always use `ENV.fetch` instead of brackets (`ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL')`). This will raise a KeyError if the env var is not set and fail early instead of letting the app boot up and then blow up with a nil error. Its saved me so much debugging time.

Comment: Is the `REDIS_URL` actually set in your Heroku configuration?

Comment: @max Thank you.  I will investigate

Comment: @spickermann Supposedly.  I had 3 people from the GoRails.com community help investigate, and they all confirm the REDIS_URL is correct.

Comment: Hi @MonroeMann do you have the final fix for this issue?

Comment: Hi @alexventuraio yes, we fixed it.  I am reviewing what we did, and will post an update shortly.  I am sorry that I am only seeing your comment today.

Comment: Hi @MonroeMann, any updates you are able to share please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this thread while looking for a solution. The fix was this in sidekiq.rb:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }
end
```

See https://ogirginc.github.io/en/heroku-redis-ssl-error for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get it working, and I'm trying now to remember what we did.  Some of the possibilities:

1. We updated redis on Heroku from redis-to-go to actual redis.
2. We updated the REDIS_URL
3. We actually fully deleted the entire redis instance, and then created a new one.  I believe this is what @spickermann above alluded to.

Eventually, one of those solutions ended up working. I regret it's been so long that I cannot say with certainty, but... I am almost certain it is related to 2 and 3 above.